# StartActivity crashes in ListView.setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, crash, android-activity

I have an odd issue with starting an activity. I am able to start it from a menu using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,SplashScreen.class);
this.startActivity(intent);
```

but if i try starting it from ListView.setOnItemClickListener, it crashes. However i tried all kind of methods, the result is the same (the activity i wanna start is a blank screen, so nothing suspicious about it).
 Here is the current code...

```
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), SplashScreen.class));
            }});
```

The activity is added to the manifest... And the main class extends activity.

The LogCat

```
02-23 17:17:11.070: W/dalvikvm(3200): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ro.pca.rentme/ro.pca.rentme.SplashScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at ro.pca.rentme.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:46)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace from logcat

Comment: have u tried to copy the `MainActivity` in a global activity variable , and then use the variable to start `SplashScreen.class` instead of using `getBaseContext()`

Comment: no, i didn't. i'll try now.

Comment: Shoshi, your method is not working.

Comment: post your `SplashScreen.java`, your problem is in `SplashScreen.java`'s 46 no line

Comment: We so need to see: ro.pca.rentme.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:46)

Answer (score 0):

you do not need `getBaseContext()` use your activity name with this.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    startActivity(new Intent(YourActivityName.this, SplashScreen.class));
  }
});
```

Make sure both activities at the manifest:

```
 <application ...>
    <activity android:name="your.package.name.MainActivity" /> <!-- or .MainActivity -->
    <activity android:name="your.package.name.SplashScreen" />
 </application>
```

Comment: same crash, identical catlog. I have them added correctly. The SplasScreen class, works correctly when app is started with Intent intent = new Intent(this,SplashScreen.class); this.startActivity(intent);

Comment: post `02-23 17:17:11.248: E/AndroidRuntime(3200):     at ro.pca.rentme.SplashScreen.onCreate(SplashScreen.java:46)` the problem is not then on starting activity but the activity itself!

Comment: the activity is blank. it only contains a picture (imageview).

Comment: that seems to be weird! have you checked the manifest code I added? also try clean & built!

Comment: yes, the manifest is perfect. may the problem be that the onclicklistener doesn't use the @override ?

Comment: what is at `SplashScreen.java:46` ?

Comment: a blank activity which displays a picture.

Comment: i also tried creating new activities and calling them from different places of the code, and they work. the single place where it refuses to work is in the onitemclicklistener event.

Comment: Update: the damn thing works now, but the cure was removing from the manifest the target api; so now i only have left in the manifest 'android:minSdkVersion="3"'.i'll try find a better cure and let you all know.